# Spring Cloud config to java util Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-cloud

I am using using spring cloud (with spring boot) to create some micro services. Now I have enabled quartz scheduling for one of the services. Following is the code snippet (trimmed):

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Now I do not like this quartz.properties file and want to share this config through spring cloud config server (I have one already). If I put these config there I am able to get them through `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` but I don't get how can I fetch then as `java.util.Properties` to pass to the `SchedulerFactoryBean.setQuartzProperties()`. I do not want to read 1 by 1 and set.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind `Properties` to `@ConfigurationProperties` but you can bind a `Map<String,String>` and convert it manually.

Comment: Binding a `Map<String, String>` to `@ConfigurationProperties` results in a Map<String, Map> because Spring starts creating sub-maps if you have periods in property names.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe there's something pathological about your property values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get it to work:

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.putAll(StreamSupport
        .stream(((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().spliterator(), false)
        .filter(propertySource -> propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
        .map(propertySource -> (EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource)
        .map(EnumerablePropertySource::getPropertyNames)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(propertyName -> propertyName.startsWith("quartz."))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            propertyName -> propertyName.replaceAll("^quartz\\.", ""),
            propertyName -> env.getProperty(propertyName),
            (key1, key2) -> key1
        )));

    return properties;
}
```